# Gnome Terminal keeps appending prompt when window is resized

Tags: bash, terminal, ps1

For some reason whenever I shrink my terminal window to be shorter than my prompt, it will start appending my prompts on to one another. Below are all the lines in my `.bashrc` file that are concerned with the `PS1` environment variable

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]'
```

and

```
export PS1="$PS1\$(__git_ps1)\[\033[00m\]\$ "
```

The problem I'm talking about can be seen in the following screenshots:
[image: initial Picture]

[image: After using corner drag to shrink]

[image: After using corner drag to return to original size]